# How to convert the last 3 digits of the number?

Tags: javascript, numbers

How to convert the last 3 digits of the number? Numbers will be bigger then 8000.

For example:

From 249439 to 249000?

Comment: How do you want `500` and `501` to be rounded?

Comment: Numbers will be bigger then 8000

Comment: Then let me rephrase. How do you want `8500` and `8501` to be rounded?

Comment: 8500 and 8501 round to 8000

Comment: @korvinko What about 8501?

Comment: Do you want *rounding* or *flooring*?

Comment: I need last 3 digits of the number convert to zero.

Comment: So you're neither rounding, nor flooring, you're simply converting whatever the last three numbers are to `000`?

Comment: So 8999 gets converted to 8000 instead of 9000?

Comment: Yes, 8999 will convert to 8000

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the last three digits using the modulus operator `%`, which (for positive numbers) computes the remainder after integer division; for example, `249439 % 1000` is `439`.

So to round down to the nearest thousand, you can just subtract those three digits:

```
var rounded = original - original % 1000;
```

(for example, if `original` is `249439`, then `rounded` will be `249000`).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

```
function roundLastNDigits (num, digits) {
    // making sure the variables exist, and are numbers; if *not* we quit at this point:
    if (!num || !parseInt(num,10) || !digits || !parseInt(digits,10)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        /* otherwise we:
           - divide the number by 10 raised to the number of digits
             (to shift divide the number so that those digits follow
             the decimal point), then
           - we round that number, then
           - multiply by ten raised to the number of digits (to
             recreate the same 'size' number/restoring the decimal fraction
             to an integer 'portion' */
        return Math.round(num / Math.pow(10, parseInt(digits,10))) * Math.pow(10,digits);
    }
}

console.log(roundLastNDigits(249439, 3))
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3TtZP/).

If you'd prefer to always round *down*, I'd amend the above to give:

```
function roundLastNDigits (num, digits) {
    if (!num || !parseInt(num,10) || !digits || !parseInt(digits,10)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return Math.floor(num / Math.pow(10, parseInt(digits,10))) * Math.pow(10,digits);
    }
}

console.log(roundLastNDigits(8501, 3))
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3TtZP/2/).

Simplifying the above by incorporating [ruakh's *genius* approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18367347/82548):

```
function roundLastNDigits (num, digits) {
    if (!num || !parseInt(num,10) || !digits || !parseInt(digits,10)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return num - (num % Math.pow(10,parseInt(digits,10)));
    }
}

console.log(roundLastNDigits(8501, 3))
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3TtZP/4/).

Or, finally, given that you only need to replace the last three digit characters with 0:

```
function roundLastNDigits (num, digits) {
    if (!num || !digits || !parseInt(digits,10)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var reg = new RegExp('\\d{' + digits + '}$');
        return num.toString().replace(reg, function (a) {
            return new Array(parseInt(digits,10) + 1).join(0);
        });
    }
}

console.log(roundLastNDigits(8501, 3))
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3TtZP/5/).

References:

- [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).
- [`Math.pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).
- [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 0):

For always rounding down I'd suggest dividing out `1000`, casting to *Int* then multipling back in `1000`

```
var x = 249439,
    y = ((x / 1000) | 0) * 1000; // 249000
```

Comment: There are no ints in JS.

Comment: None of those types are accessible to the user. Every number you actually work with is a 64-bit float

Comment: @NullUserException this does not prevent you from performing an action which will do the cast.

Comment: Any particular reason for using this strategy?

Comment: Just one example perf I found quickly; http://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/88 showing bitwise operators marginally faster. Personally I think it looks a lot cleaner and has other benifits when it comes to _NaN_, _undefined_, or casting strings etc

Answer (score 0):

1)
    Math.round(num.toPrecision(3));

This doesn't account for the values before the 3rd value to round.

2)

This is sort of a bad solution but it works.
num = 50343 // whatever your input is.

m = 10^n.

Math.round(num*m)/m

n being the amount you want to move over.